# How to store and retrieve data(SQL) via Connection in android

Tags: java, android, sql, web, connection

I would like to make a "Market" thing in my game and I would like to store data(SQL table) somewhere and retrieve it from it. I have got all logic but now i am stuck.

How can i set-up server, store data on it and retireve it from it.
What's the easiest way to do it?

it should work like this:
1 User is adding some information into database and my app is sending it to the "Server" and then other users can retrieve that informations from server.

Any Help, tutorial would help me ALOT. Sorry for my english :|.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cloud storage complete with DB and security. Many to choose from I use GAE. 
[Google app engine](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) They actually just started to use SQL if that is a requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to three thing 
1.phpFileName(where coding is written to retrieve data) i.e. server side coding
2.array of data(which is being send from android file)
3.no. of data in that array

Or you can use Asyncro Task for get Server data
On this link you can see a easy tutorial.
http://shahzadimam.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/save-data-to-php-server-from-android/

For other's access use cloud storage facilities. Or If you have money setup your own server.

For more help Google it.